# Sign with eID remember PIN

Tags: vb.net, itext, pkcs#11

I am trying to sign a series (thousands) of PDF with a Belgian eID token while only asking the user's PIN once. Something is wrong with giving my pin as an argument to the function:

```
        Dim pin As String = "1234"
        Using pkcs11rsaSignature As Pkcs11RsaSignature = New Pkcs11RsaSignature(librarypath, tokenserial, tokenlabel, pin, ckalabel, ckaId, Net.Pkcs11Interop.PDF.HashAlgorithm.SHA1)
        Dim signingCertificate = pkcs11rsaSignature.GetSigningCertificate()
        Dim otherCertificates = pkcs11rsaSignature.GetAllCertificates()
        Dim certPath = CertUtils.BuildCertPath(signingCertificate, otherCertificates)

        Using pdfreader As PdfReader = New PdfReader(unsignedPdfPath)
            Using outputstream As FileStream = New FileStream(signedPdfPath, FileMode.Create)
                Using PdfStamper As PdfStamper = PdfStamper.CreateSignature(pdfreader, outputstream, "0"c, Path.GetTempFileName(), True)
                    MakeSignature.SignDetached(PdfStamper.SignatureAppearance, pkcs11rsaSignature, certPath, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, 0, CryptoStandard.CADES)
                End Using
            End Using
        End Using
    End Using
```

I am using this code but getting a FormatException: No recognizable numbers found. How can I solve my problem?

bdebaere

Answer (score 0):

You can safely reuse single instance of `Pkcs11RsaSignature` class to create multiple signatures. Take a look at [Pkcs11RsaSignatureReuseTest](https://github.com/jariq/Pkcs11Interop.PDF/blob/master/src/Pkcs11Interop.PDF.Tests/Pkcs11RsaSignatureTest.cs#L712) which signs 100 PDF documents.

Comment: Thank you so much for your input! That looks like the code that I need to sign a folder full of PDFs. However my issue is with the pin. How can I pass my pin as argument to the function? The way I am doing it now currently gives an exception.

Comment: @bdebaere Can you please post the exception along with the full stack trace?

Comment: Yes here is the stacktrace: "   bij System.ParseNumbers.StringToInt(String s, Int32 radix, Int32 flags, Int32* currPos)     bij System.Convert.ToByte(String value, Int32 fromBase)     bij Net.Pkcs11Interop.Common.ConvertUtils.HexStringToBytes(String value)     bij Net.Pkcs11Interop.PDF.Pkcs11RsaSignature..ctor(String libraryPath, String tokenSerial, String tokenLabel, String pin, String ckaLabel, String ckaId, HashAlgorithm hashAlgorihtm)     bij SignMyPDF.SignMyPDF.test4() in C:\Users\Brecht\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\SignMyPDF\SignMyPDF\SignMyPDF.vb:regel 90"

Comment: @bdebaere It seems that you are passing incorrect value of `ckaId` parameter to the constructor of `Pkcs11RsaSignature` class. Please take a look at [Pkcs11Interop.PDF.Demo](https://github.com/jariq/Pkcs11Interop.PDF/blob/master/src/Pkcs11Interop.PDF.Demo/DemoApp.cs#L410) application which demonstrates the correct usage of Pkcs11Interop.PDF library.

Comment: Ok thank you! I changed the ckaId to its correct value. However the code still asks me for a pin on every signing operation.

Comment: @bdebaere How does it ask you? Does some kind of PIN dialog appear? This may be caused by the internal format of your eID card which requires the PIN to be provided for every single signing operation. I am not familiar with the format of Belgian eID but if you are willing to invest some time and troubleshoot the issue I will gladly help you with some custom code. Just drop me an e-mail to jaroslav (dot) imrich (at) gmail (dot) com.

Answer (score 0):

The Belgian eID middleware forces a PIN dialog for every signature operation, due to legal requirements.